# Rails : Poltergeist doesn't seem to find an fully working phantomjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, phantomjs, poltergeist

I've created a small Rails app that checks recularly the content of one of my sites with poltergeist and Capybara. Everything works great in dev on my mac. 
But when I test it on my production server I get the following server.

Capybara::Poltergeist::PhantomJSFailed (PhantomJS returned non-zero exit status 127. Make sure phantomjs runs successfully on your system. You can test this by just running the `phantomjs` command which should give you a Javascript REPL.):

Phantomjs works. I've tested it from the command-line.
And what puzzles me more is that it also works when I run my method from the rails console on the production server.

Any idea?

Comment: I've started experiencing a similar issue: PhantomJS works perfectly fine on my local machine and crashes on CI. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I was having the same issues. 1. do you gave qt installed in production?

Comment: Is it a $PATH issue? Sometimes system daemons run with a different $PATH to user services, so phantomjs may not be on your path when run from httpd

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, Just I cant remember exactly what I did to recreate it. May have been me trying to do this on a virtual linux machine.

But this link https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist/issues/346 seems to detail 2 potential issues.

1. Is probably to do with $path
2. Could be a memory issue.